# Split in awk not not printing array values

Tags: awk, array

I have a string tstArr2 which has the following content

```
'3 5 8'
```

Now in awk I want to parse a flat file

```
test my array which array is better array

INDIA USA SA NZ AUS ARG GER BRA
US AUS INDIA ENG NZ SRI PAK WI BAN NED IRE
```

at these numbered columns only.
I tried the following

```
awk -vA="$tstArr2" 'BEGIN{split(A,B," ");} {if(NR>1){for(i=1; i<= length(B); i++){printf "%s ",B[i]}}print " "}' testUnix3.txt
```

But it says

```
awk: Cannot read the value of  B. It is an array name.

The input line number is 2. The file is testUnix3.txt.
The source line number is 1.
```

What am I missing ?
If I try the following

```
awk -vA="$tstArr2" 'BEGIN{split(A,B," ");} {if(NR>1){for(i in B){printf "%s ",$B[i]}}print " "}' testUnix3.txt
```

it prints the outputs but they are not in order. I want them to be in order. 
Please explain.
Desired output :

```
 SA AUS BRA

 INDIA NZ WI
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you see with the first code sample.  What version of `awk` are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POSIX defined [length](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13) in `awk` is a string function, argument taken as a string. Using `length` with an array as argument is unspecified behavior.

In some implementations of `awk` like [gawk (version >= 3.1.6)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), [OS X version of AWK](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Howawk-ward/Howawk-ward.html), you can use `length` with an array as argument, it will return number of elements in array.

Array in `awk` is associative array, looping through associative array does not guarantee anything about the order. In this case, you can take advantage of [split](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13) function, which return number of fields to get the number elements of array.

POSIXly, you can try:

```
$ awk -vA="$tstArr2" '
  BEGIN{n = split(A,B," ");}
  {
    if(NR > 1) {
      for(i = 1;i <= n;i++) {
        printf "%s ",$B[i];
      }
    }
    print " ";
  }
' file

SA AUS BRA  
INDIA NZ WI
```

Comment: Oh !! Superb explanation . Glad you helped me through.

Answer (score 2):

(For non-GNU awk, please see @cuonglm's answer.)

With this as the test file:

```
$ cat testUnix3.txt 
test my array which array is better array

INDIA USA SA NZ AUS ARG GER BRA
US AUS INDIA ENG NZ SRI PAK WI BAN NED IRE
```

This code selects columns 3, 5, and 8:

```
$ tstArr2='3 5 8'
$ awk  -vA="$tstArr2" 'BEGIN{split(A,B," ");} NR>1{for(i=1; i<= length(B); i++) printf "%s ",$B[i]; print "";}' testUnix3.txt

SA AUS BRA 
INDIA NZ WI
```

The above was tested with GNU `awk`.

#### `awk` loops and order

`awk` has associative arrays.   As the [Grymoire awk tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-23)  explains:

> There is one minor problem with associative arrays, especially if you
>   use the **for** command to output each element: you have no control over
>   the order of output.

That is the reason why the other code that you cited, which uses a `for(i in B)` loop, may, at times, print columns out of order.

GNU awk has an extension to overcome this issue:

```
$ gawk -vA="$tstArr2" 'BEGIN{split(A,B," "); PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"} {if(NR>1){for(i in B){printf "%s ",$B[i]}print " "}}' testUnix3.txt

SA AUS BRA  
INDIA NZ WI
```

By setting `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"`, the indices will be looped over in numeric ascending order.  This GNU extension is documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning).

Comment: Using `length` with an array as argument is not defined by POSIX, see my answer.

Comment: @cuonglm I think that you have correctly identified the OP's problem with the first code sample.  My tests were done with GNU awk.

Answer (score 1):

There is much overhead to use so powerful instrument as `awk` for such simple task:

```
tstArr2='3,5,8'
tail -n+2 testUnix3.txt | cut -d' ' -f"$tstArr2"
```

Comment: nice and smooth one!!